# Fastest Way to Update a bunch of records in queryset in Django

Tags: python, database, django, django-queryset

I have a queryset with a few million records. I need to update a Boolean Value, fundamentally toggle it, so that in the database table the values are reset. What's the fastest way to do that?

I tried traversing the queryset and updating and saving each record, that obviously takes ages? We need to do this very fast, any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See the [documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/topics/db/queries/#updating-multiple-objects-at-once):

```
Entry.objects.all().update(value= not F('value'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, that didn't work out for me.

The following did:

`Entry.objects.all().update(value=(F('value')==False))`

Answer (score 0):

Actually, none of the suggested solutions worked. I believe they did work at some point, but not anymore.

The problem is that Django evaluates `not F('value')` as False.
You can try this yourself by testing in python shell

```
not F('is_featured')
```

vs.

```
for example F('is_featured') + 1
```

This happens because Django doesn't support negation/not in F expressions. [Here](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/16211) is the discussion about the topic: a lot was discussed, but in the end the issue was left unresolved. 8 years and counting.

Fortunately there is a solution. I found it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40402120/invert-boolean-field-in-update-operations-with-f).
You will have to use [Case When](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/conditional-expressions/#case)

```
from django.db.models import Case, Value, When

Item.objects.filter(serial__in=license_ids
).update(renewable=Case(
    When(renewable=True, then=Value(False)),
    default=Value(True))
    )
)
```

Sometimes you [might want to use](https://tomforb.es/bulk-update-lands-in-django-2.2/) `bulk_update` instead of the ordinary `update`.

Interestingly, the implementation of the `bulk_update` [relies](https://tomforb.es/bulk-update-lands-in-django-2.2/) on the exact same Case/When/Then/Value shenanigans as in the solution I provided above.