# Invert boolean field in update operations with F()

Tags: django

I need, through an `update` operation, revert a `boolean` value.

I tried:

```
Item.objects.filter(serial__in=license_ids).update(renewable=not F('renewable'))
```

But it doesn't work. I made sure the fields are not set to `null`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Not is not supported here. You will have to use [Case When](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/conditional-expressions/#case)

```
from django.db.models import Case, Value, When

Item.objects.filter(serial__in=license_ids
).update(renewable=Case(
    When(renewable=True, then=Value(False)),
    default=Value(True))
    )
)
```

Answer (score 17):

You can also do:

```
Item.objects.filter(serial__in=license_ids).update(renewable=Q(renewable=False))
```

when renewable is `True` => Q object condition will give `False`

when renewable is `False` => Q object condition will give `True`

[Django docs for `Q()` objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.Q).