# Django: endpoint to reverse status not working

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, endpoint

I'm learning and experimenting with DRF.

I'm learning actions to create routes (endpoints) to make custom modifications to my models.

I succesfully have constructed: `deactivate`, `deactivate_all`, `activate_all`.

But not `reverse_status`, which is meant to change the current status of a customer to the opposite. If `customer.active = True`, this would change it to `False` and viceversa.

my action:

```
@action(detail=False, methods=['PUT']) #when true only applies to 1 object / else to a list of objects
def reverse_status(self, request, **kwargs):
    customers = Customer.objects.all()
    import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
    customers = [customer.update(active=False) for customer in customers if customer.active]            
    serializer = CustomerSerializer(customers, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

As you notice, I've set a breakpoint to see what customers holds after the list comprenhension, but it gets converted to an empty list:

**Original:**

```
<QuerySet [<Customer: Gregory>, <Customer: Julia>, <Customer: Naty>]>
```

**After List Comprehension:**

```
[]
```

**Why?**

Comment: What are the values of `active` for those customers?  If they're already `False`, then they won't make it into the list...

Comment: @RishiG, ... they where all false. But now I'm getting: `*** AttributeError: 'Customer' object has no attribute 'update'`

Comment: yeah, that's a method on queryset, not on model objects

Comment: @RishiG tried `customers = [customer.active=False for customer in customers if customer.active]` but says invalid syntax.

Comment: yup, that's not a valid python construct

Comment: howcome? I've read things like: `var = <value>` like `car.color = 'red'` all the time.

Comment: `customer.update(active=False)` does not output anything, this is why you are getting an empty list in list comprehension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```py
@action(detail=False, methods=['PUT'])
def reverse_status(self, request, **kwargs):
    active_customers = Customer.objects.filter(active=True)
    active_customers.update(active=False)
    serializer = CustomerSerializer(active_customers, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

#### Update: address actual intention, which is a two-way reversal

This should do the trick:

```py
@action(detail=False, methods=['PUT'])
def reverse_status(self, request, **kwargs):
    Customer.objects.update(active=Q(active=False))
    serializer = CustomerSerializer(Customer.objects.all(), many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

Here the `Q(active=False)` construct does the magic of flipping the boolean.

#### Update2: very incomplete note on `Q` in update

The [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#query-related-tools) on `Q` is a little short and open-ended.  There are a ton of examples on using it in filter expressions, but the description hints at more general use:

> A Q() object, like an F object, encapsulates a SQL expression in a
>   Python object that can be used in database-related operations.
>
> In general, Q() objects make it possible to define and reuse
>   conditions. This permits the construction of complex database queries
>   using | (OR) and & (AND) operators; in particular, it is not otherwise
>   possible to use OR in QuerySets.

The phrase "define and reuse conditions" is apparently a pretty powerful and general statement.  To be honest I'm not sure where I first learned that you could use it beyond `filter`, but [here is an S/O answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54250248/2715819) with an example.

Comment: Thank you. it works, but solves the case for True to False (active to inactive), but not False to True (inactive to active). That's why was trying to do a `conditional` in a `list comprehension`.

Comment: Sorry, I was just responding to the code, not the intention.  Will update

Comment: Would you explain in a more detail your answer? Read https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects and as I understand `Q objects` are for complex quering. I don't really understand how is that that `Q objects` changes the active value of each object. But it works. Ty.

Comment: `Customer.objects.update(active=Q(active=False))` sets `active` to whatever the comparison of `active` to False was. If `active` is True then comparison to False is False and `active `gets set to False. And the other way around for True.